# How to add custom file start in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to add a custom start comment in any new file that is created in Visual Studio, but I cannot find the way to do it. I use C++ under VisualStudio2015 and I want every file (cpp or hpp) to start like this:

```
/*
* Project <project_name> or <file_name>
* 
* Created by <user_name>
* on <date>
*
* Description: To be completed ...
*/
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is a "custom start file"? Are you just talking about a *comment block* at the top of each file? You might be interested in the [Atomineer Utilities](http://www.atomineerutils.com/).

Comment: I need a header in each file, but I was trying to avoid header for not confusing with the .h files...So, what you are suggesting is pretty nice, thanks. There is an error, it should be "custom start", sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[License Header Manager](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5647a099-77c9-4a49-91c3-94001828e99e) extension allows you to add a predefined header to new and existing files.

Comment: Do you use it? can you give some info about adding date, user and filename, please?

Comment: @sop See Expandable Properties https://github.com/rubicon-oss/LicenseHeaderManager/wiki/Expendable-Properties